# pygame.display.get_surface() возвращает None, а не Surface

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame as pg

pg.init()

...

class BuildingGUI:

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):

        self.display_surface = pg.display.get_surface()
        print(self.display_surface)
        
        ...
```

`print(self.display_surface)` выводит: `None`

При этом друой класс (я его скопировал, чтобы написать этот) из этого же файла, который тоже имеет строчку `self.display_surface = pg.display.get_surface()`, получает Surface-объект.
Как это исправить?

Answer (score 0):

В файле я добавил sc = `pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))`, что, вероятно, создает display, с которого мы функцией `pg.display.get_surface()` получаем его поверхность. Теперь `pg.display.get_surface()` работает

Comment: похоже, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите